# How do I Combine/Merge two Map of Map of Lists (Map<String, Map<Enum, List<String>>>) in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Given:
A Map containing FRUITS

```
enum Food{
FRUITS, VEGGIES;
}

Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> fruitBasket= new HashMap<>();
fruitBasket.put("basket1", Collections.singletonMap(Food.FRUITS, Arrays.asList("apple","banana")));
fruitBasket.put("basket2", Collections.singletonMap(Food.FRUITS, Arrays.asList"orange", "kiwi")));
fruitBasket.put("basket3", Collections.singletonMap(Food.FRUITS, Arrays.asList("banana", "orange")));

fruitBasket:
[
basket1, [Food.FRUITS, {"apple", "banana"}],
basket2, [Food.FRUITS, {"orange", "kiwi"}],
basket3, [Food.FRUITS, {"banana", "orange"}]
]
```

Similarly another map containing VEGGIES

```
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> veggieBasket= new HashMap<>();
veggieBasket.put("basket1", Collections.singletonMap(Food.VEGGIES, Arrays.asList("Tomato","Onion")));
veggieBasket.put("basket2", Collections.singletonMap(Food.VEGGIES, Arrays.asList("Onion", "Potato")));
veggieBasket.put("basket3", Collections.singletonMap(Food.VEGGIES, Arrays.asList("Potato", "Tomato")));

veggieBasket:
[
basket1, [Food.VEGGIES, {"Tomato","Onion"}],
basket2, [Food.VEGGIES, {"Onion", "Potato"}],
basket3, [Food.VEGGIES, {"Potato", "Tomato"}]
]
```

I am trying to combine the baskets *fruitBasket* and *veggieBasket*

```
Final output: should look something like below

groceryBasket
[
basket1, [Food.FRUITS, {"apple", "banana"}, Food.VEGGIES, {"Tomato","Onion"}],
basket2, [Food.FRUITS, {"orange", "kiwi"}, Food.VEGGIES, {"Onion", "Potato"}],
basket3, [Food.FRUITS, {"banana", "orange"}, Food.VEGGIES, {"Potato", "Tomato"}]
]
```

MySolution:

```
Solution 1:
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> groceryBasket= new HashMap<>();

grocery basket = Stream.concat(fruitBasket.entrySet().stream(), veggieBasket.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (fruitList, veggieList ) ->
                {
                    final List<String> groceryList = new ArrayList<>();
                    groceryList .addAll(fruitList);
                    groceryList .addAll(veggieList);
                    return groceryList;
                }));

Solution 2:
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> groceryBasket= new HashMap<>();

grocery basket = Stream.concat(fruitBasket.entrySet().stream(), veggieBasket.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (fruitList, veggieList ) ->
                {
                    return Stream.of(fruitList, veggieList).flatMap(x -> x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                }));
```

I tried Solutions 1 and Solution 2, I was trying to thing if there is a better/optimized way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> groceryBasket = 
   Stream.concat(fruitBasket.entrySet().stream(),veggieBasket.entrySet().stream())
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, v -> v.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)),
                    (a, b) -> { a.putAll(b);return a; }
                   )
               );
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try resolving the merge as:

```
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> groceryBasket =
        Stream.concat(fruitBasket.entrySet().stream(), veggieBasket.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> {
                    Map<Food, List<String>> innerMap = new HashMap<>(a);
                    innerMap.putAll(b);
                    return innerMap;
                }));
```

or if the inner map is mutable then slightly convenient as

```
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> groceryBasket = Stream.concat(fruitBasket.entrySet().stream(),
        veggieBasket.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> {
            a.putAll(b);
            return a;
        }));
```

Comment: because its a `singletonMap - immutable`

Comment: @HadiJ correct, edited in the answer. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create modifiable List for merging duplicate keys,

```
Stream.concat(fruitBasket.entrySet().stream(), veggieBasket.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> listOf(e.getValue()),
                        (left, right) -> {
                            left.addAll(right);
                            return left;
                        }));
```

To create modifiable List,

```
public static List<Map<Food, List<String>>> listOf(Map<Food, List<String>> a) {
    final ArrayList<Map<Food, List<String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(a);
    return list;
}
```

Output:

> {basket3=[{FRUITS=[banana, orange]}, {VEGGIES=[Potato, Tomato]}],
>
> basket2=[{FRUITS=[orange, kiwi]}, {VEGGIES=[Onion, Potato]}],
>
> basket1=[{FRUITS=[apple, banana]}, {VEGGIES=[Tomato, Onion]}]}

Comment: and what would be the return type of your solution?